# javascript generating php doens't works

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello I have an option list in html that is created dynamically by php. I want to take the value of the option list withought subbmiting everything and then call another php function to fill another option list. To be more specific I want the user to first pick a University from a database and then to pick a department of that Universe. I 've created dynamicaly the option list for the Uni's by fetching all Uni's from the database and then find the value by javascript. So in the javascript function I want to write php code in order to fetch all the departments from the university. Eveything works fine until I try to call the php function from the javascript.

signup.php

```
<form>
<table>
.
.
.
 <tr>
    <td> Ίδρυμα:</td> 
    <td><select id="selection" name="selection" onchange="selectDep()" >
         <?php include './selectUni.php'; ?>
    </select>  </td>
    <td><span id="orgError" style="display: none;"></span> <td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td> Τμήμα:</td> 
     <td id="dep" name="dep" ></td>
     <td><span id="depError" style="display: none;"></span><td>
  </tr>
.
.
</table>
</form>
```

generateDep.js

```
function selectDep(){
    if(document.getElementById('selection').value === "---")
        return;

    var value=document.getElementById('selection').value;
   alert(value);
    document.getElementById('dep').innerHTML="  <?php include './selectDep.php'; selectDep("+value+"); ?> ";
    return true;
}
```

the value at the alert is correct

selectDep.php

```
<?php

//just trying to make this work for now
function selectDep($value){
    echo $value;
}
?>
```

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. Everything look fine to me. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server-side scripting language. It is executed on the server, which means the page has to submit values to the server as a trigger.  Javascript and HTML are client-side, which means it's all done in the browser without communicating with the server.

To see this in action, right-click on a PHP page in the browser and select to view source. All you will see is the HTML, you will not be able to view any of the PHP code that generates the page. When PHP executes on the server, the result is client-side code (javascript, HTML and maybe CSS) which is sent to the browser.

The browser wouldn't know what to do with PHP code. If you set the inner HTML of an element to some PHP code in client-side script, it won't get executed and all you will achieve is having the browser render the PHP script exactly as you entered it.

In short, the javascript has to submit the selected value back to the server, before the server-side PHP can work out which departments to send back to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

First You have to understand that the javascript code executes in **web browser** but the php code executes in **web server**.

You can use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) to fix your problem.